# How to check performance of the linear regression algorithm and improve?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have implemented Linear Regression using tensorflow on [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/muhammetvarl/laptop-price) to predict Laptop prices after given specs. I plan to use this on a web app that can give the user a budget for the laptop according to their requirements.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
import tensorflow.compat.v2.feature_column as fc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv('laptop_price.csv', encoding = 'latin-1')
df['Weight']=df['Weight'].replace('kg','',regex=True).astype(float)
df['Ram']=df['Ram'].replace('GB','',regex=True).astype(int)
df.rename(columns = {'Weight':'Weight (kg)'}, inplace = True)
df.rename(columns = {'Ram':'Ram (GB)'}, inplace = True)

final_dataset = df[['Company', 'TypeName', 'Inches', 'ScreenResolution', 'Cpu', 'Ram (GB)', 'Memory', 'Gpu', 'OpSys', 'Weight (kg)', 'Price_euros']]

columns = list(df)
columns.remove('laptop_ID')

NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['Inches', 'Weight (kg)', 'Ram (GB)']
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = []
for item in columns:
    if item not in (NUMERIC_COLUMNS):
        CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS.append(item)
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS.remove('Price_euros')
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS.remove('Product')
feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  vocabulary = final_dataset[feature_name].unique()  
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocabulary))

for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.float32))

print(feature_columns)

X = final_dataset.iloc[:,final_dataset.columns!= 'Price_euros']
y = final_dataset['Price_euros']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  def input_function(): 
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df)) 
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(1000)  
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)  
    return ds 
  return input_function 
train_input_fn = make_input_fn(X_train, y_train) 
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(X_test, y_test, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns, model_dir=None, label_dimension=1, weight_column=None,
    optimizer='Ftrl', config=None, warm_start_from=None,
    sparse_combiner='sum'
)

linear_est.train(train_input_fn) 
result = linear_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)

clear_output()  
print(result)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
{'average_loss': 1481760.6, 'label/mean': 1178.7135, 'loss': 1454420.2, 'prediction/mean': 202.05832, 'global_step': 290}
```

After training the model multiple times, the average loss and loss is decreasing and prediction mean is getting closer to the label/mean, while the global step has been increasing. Should I keep training the model till label/mean and predcition/mean are equal?

Is there a better way to improve the predictions?

Comment: Use `Tensorflow Profiler` tool to measure the model performance. Tensorflow profiler is inbuilt with Tensorboard. View the performance profiles by navigating to the Profile tab. Based on the Performance summary and graph you can tune the hyperparameters to improve the accuracy. For more details about the library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras). Thanks!